# 'alert' is not a known element ngx boostrap

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I've installed ngx bootstrap

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap@2 --save
```

imported the module for as described in the [documentation](https://ngx-bootstrap-latest.surge.sh/#/alerts)

```
// RECOMMENDED (doesn't work with system.js)
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/alert';
// or
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [AlertModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

However when I use the component

```
 <alert  *ngIf="success" type="success"> Alert text</alert>
```

I get;

```
'alert' is not a known element:
1. If 'alert' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

I added the 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA', but still no joy

Comment: does the usage of the <alert> tag is in AppModule components? or its used in another module?

Comment: Just checked, I have no other components named alert, also I don't need to add alert to the declarations of the AppModule? according to the documention

Comment: here is a demo, it works:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u8yu7k

Comment: are you having this <alert></alert> in component related to app.module.ts? Or does the component have other module.ts?

Answer (score 1):

Got it, the component I was using the alert in was being declared in a feature module (CrudModule) and being imported into the main AppModule, once I imported the AlertModule into the CrudModule, it worked

Answer (score 0):

The recommended is to use this form:

```
// RECOMMENDED
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/alert';
```

You can also consult the documentation for more questions [documentation ngx api](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/alerts)

After that, use the code below on an html page:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> Success example.</div>
```

You must use the components on this page:
[bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/alerts/)

For CSS components you must use this official bootstrap page, but for components that have some action such as *"dropdown"* button for example, you must use the documentation contained on the website [ngxl-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns).

**Note:** Pay attention to the versions of your Angular, ngx-bootstrap and the Bootstrap you are using. To see the compatibility of each one take a look at this page: [compatibility ngx-bootstrap whith Angular and Bootstrap CSS](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation#api).